# Does Appdynamics provide any APIs for creating project/job and user

Tags: python, appdynamics

I Have tried to find if Appdynamics provides any API but I could not find any. So I want to know if there are any APIs available for creating users and project/job in Appdynamics, so that I can automate the process using Python scripts.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of APIs available out of the box, you can find the docs at https://docs.appdynamics.com/ not everything has an API. You should find the user management as part of the configuration API here : https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO42/Configuration+API